# how to optimise an sql union containing joins and a subquery

Tags: mysql, php-5.3

I have looked at the many comments regarding sql optimisation but I cannot find an answer.

My app uses this sql  ...

```
SELECT * FROM ((
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      c.companyname,
      c.tradingas,
      a.quarantined,
      c.companyid,
      a.address1,
      a.city,
      a.postcode,
      a.region,
      c.origin_dsn,
      d.title,
      d.firstname,
      d.surname,
      d.position,
      a.telephoneno,
      a.companyemail,
      addresstypes,
      markets 
    FROM companies c
    join addresses a on c.companyid = a.companyid
    join contacts d on c.companyid = d.companyid
    where d.origin_dsn = 'ifd'
      and primarycontact = 1
      and d.clientid = 0
      and c.origin_dsn = 'ifd' and
      a.origin_dsn = 'ifd' and
      c.companyid in (
        select distinct companyid
        from products
        where description IN ('Windows and Doors','Vertical Sliders','Bi-Fold Doors')
          AND type IN ('wd:f','wd:b')
          AND material = 'PVCu'
          AND origin_dsn = 'ifd'
  ))
  UNION (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      c.companyname,
      c.tradingas,
      a.quarantined,
      c.companyid,
      a.address1,
      a.city,
      a.postcode,
      a.region,
      c.origin_dsn,
      d.title,
      d.firstname,
      d.surname,
      d.position,
      a.telephoneno,
      a.companyemail,
      addresstypes,
      markets
    FROM companies c
    join addresses a on c.companyid = a.companyid
    join contacts d on c.companyid = d.companyid
    where d.origin_dsn = 'ifd'
      and primarycontact = 1
      and d.clientid = 0
      and c.origin_dsn = 'ifd'
      and a.origin_dsn = 'ifd'
      and c.companyid in (
        select distinct companyid
        from products
        where type IN ('cr:f','cr:b')
          AND origin_dsn = 'ifd')
      )
  ) as t
  where t.quarantined = 0
    and t.origin_dsn = 'ifd'
    and t.region IN (
      'Northern Counties','North West','Yorkshire',
      'East Midlands','West Midlands','South West',
      'Home Counties','Southern Counties','Greater London',
      'Scotland','Wales','Northern Ireland')
  order by companyname
```

it takes a staggering 3.5 seconds to run in mysql query browser (on my slow, low spec laptop)

This query is made of 2 very similar queries that each take about 1.5 seconds.

My app could require up to 4 similar unions.

Can anyone suggest how it might be written more efficiently ?

Comment: I do not believe you can optimize this query. From a question standpoint we would need to know what your tables look like, what your indexes look like and what you're trying to accomplish. From the looks of this SQL though, and your assertion that you need "up to 4 similar unions" the answer is probably that you need to rethink your design.

Comment: You have a few fields that are not alias.field (such as PrimaryContact), can you please update in the queries to remove ambiguity of which table the fields correlate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move your company product criteria up to a pre-query FIRST...
THEN Join to get the other details...   So your company ID is only ever selected once up-front. The PreQuery, you could just join the multiple criteria as I have sampled here...

```
where 
      ( first set of criteria )
   OR ( second set of criteria )
   OR ( third set of criteria )
```

(however, both your criteria use origin_dsn = 'ifd' which might be simplified once, but I don't know how your criteria is actually constructed).

To help optimize the querying, on your Products table, I would ensure
an index on (Origin_DSN, `type`, material )

FOR the address table, an index on ( companyid, origin_dsn, quarantined, region )

FOR the contacts table an index on ( companyid, origin_dsn, clientid )

Something like...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      c.companyname,
      c.tradingas,
      a.quarantined,
      c.companyid,
      a.address1,
      a.city,
      a.postcode,
      a.region,
      c.origin_dsn,
      d.title,
      d.firstname,
      d.surname,
      d.position,
      a.telephoneno,
      a.companyemail,
      addresstypes,
      markets 
   FROM 
      ( select distinct 
              p.companyid
           from 
              products p
           where 
                 (     p.origin_dsn = 'ifd' 
                   AND p.`type` IN ('cr:f','cr:b') )
              OR (     p.origin_dsn = 'ifd' 
                   AND p.`type` IN ('wd:f','wd:b')
                   AND p.material = 'PVCu' 
                   AND p.description IN ('Windows and Doors','Vertical Sliders','Bi-Fold Doors') ) ) as PreQuery

         JOIN companies c
            ON PreQuery.CompanyID = c.CompanyID


            join addresses a 
               on c.companyid = a.companyid
              and c.origin_dsn = a.origin_dsn 
              and a.quarantined = 0
              and a.Region in ( 'Northern Counties',
                                'North West',
                                'Yorkshire',
                                'East Midlands',
                                'West Midlands',
                                'South West',
                                'Home Counties',
                                'Southern Counties',
                                'Greater London',
                                'Scotland',
                                'Wales',
                                'Northern Ireland' )
            join contacts d 
               on c.companyid = d.companyid
              AND c.origin_dsn = d.origin_dsn 
              and d.clientid = 0
   where 
          primarycontact = 1
      and c.origin_dsn = 'ifd' 
   order by 
      c.companyname
```

Comment: Great post ! You have saved my skin ! Thank you very much.

Comment: An approximate 10 fold increase in speed !